# AbstractUser Signup

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

Hello I am trying to extend Django User model using Abstract User but I get OperationalError when signing up

Error:

```
OperationalError at /main/signup/
no such column: main_profile.username
```

My Profile model:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    bio = models.TextField() 
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    CREATED = 0
    ACTIVE = 1
    BANNED = 2
    KICKED = 3
    UPGRADE = 4
    STS = (
        (CREATED, 'Just Created'),
        (ACTIVE, 'Activated'),
        (BANNED, 'Disabled'),
        (KICKED, 'Disabled'),
        (UPGRADE, 'Active'),
     )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STS, default=CREATED, blank=True, null=True)
```

My Signup form:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    username = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=30,
        min_length=5,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Username",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=50,
        min_length=2,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "First name",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=50,
        min_length=2,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Last name",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    university = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=50,
        min_length=2,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "University",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='',
        max_length=255,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Email",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=30,
        min_length=8,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Password",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=30,
        min_length=8,
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Confirm Password",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:

        model = Profile
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email','university',) 

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(UserCreationForm,self).save(commit = False)
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            user.university = self.cleaned_data['university']
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

My Signup view:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.profile.university = form.cleaned_data.get('university')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            #user_login(request, user)
            return redirect('main:main_page')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

I have also added tis in setting already

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.Profile'
```

I do not understand why there is an error should AbstractUser already provide username? Or do I have to add all the fields to the Profile model, even the passwords?

Below is also my custom edit profile - I do not know if it is correct however:

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    username = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=50,
        min_length=2,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Username",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )


    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=50,
        min_length=2,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "First name",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=50,
        min_length=2,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Last name",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    university = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=50,
        min_length=2,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "University",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='',
        max_length=255,
        required=False,
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={
                "placeholder": "Email",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    bio = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                "placeholder":"Enter something about yourself",
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )


    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields=('username','first_name','last_name','email','bio',)
        def save(self, commit = True):
            user = super(UserChangeForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.bio = self.cleaned_data['bio']

            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: can you give error description

Comment: Hi, I added the the error for your reference @l-b-vasoya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `AbstractUser` it give you predefine `User` model `fields + New fields` that you define in model extend time

here when you extend user model not need to define email field explicitly due to 'User model' Have this field and when you use `UserCreationForm` it also have all pre-define field you don't need to Redefine it, In your case you define `username,first_name,last_name,email` it's not need,but if you want to take input of extra field then, you need to define extra field that you add in your model like `university` or `bio` and if you need to add `placeholder` or `bootstrap classes` you use pre_define method `def __init__` i give you stuff apply it's in you code

@model.py

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    # remove email fields
    bio = models.TextField() 
    university = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

@form.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
        university=formforms.CharField(label='',max_length=50,min_length=2)

        class Meta:
                model = Profile
                fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email','university',) 

                def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
                        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
                        for field in self.fields:
                                self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':self.fields[field].label})
```

@views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            return redirect('main:main_page')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

apply above stuff and let me know if work or not

Comment: I have changed it to what you mentioned but I am now getting:

DoesNotExist at /main/signup/
Profile matching query does not exist.

Can this be an error because of my signup view? @I-b-vasoya

Comment: Also the bootstrap does not seem to work and it shows Django common form. @I-b-vasoya

Comment: if save data in you form why reassign university again in your view

Comment: if you use field in your form it takes and save in model automatically don't assign explicitly i change my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! yes it was because I was assigning it explicitly. I can sign up now without issues @I-b-vasoya